# Open sharepoint word file in users desktop app by clicking on direct hyperlink to word document

Tags: microsoft-word, sharepoint

In our web application, we have direct link to word document in SharePoint site. So when user clicks on the hyperlink, I would like to open that in users local desktop word application. But I am unable to achieve it. I have tried other work arounds like, when user clicks on the document in the sharepoint site, able to open in word desktop app. But it is still two clicks for user to reach the word desktop app.

Is there any way if we pass any parameters in the url saying open in local desktop app?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Below is the code to open the desktop app directly in users machine. It will ask for confirmation though before opening the document in local.

editable (requires the `ofe|u` command)

`ms-word:ofe|u|https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/xxx/xx.docx`

readonly

`ms-word:https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/xxx/xx.docx`

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, I find you have got the answer on Q&A forum, "[Open sharepoint word file in users desktop app by clicking on direct hyperlink to word document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/514714/open-sharepoint-word-file-in-users-desktop-app-by.html)". I‘m glad that your issue have gone away. Please remember to accept your reply as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If Word files are stored on one document library, you may go to `library settings > advanced settings > Default open behavior for browser-enabled documents, choose **Open in the client application**`, this set is only for one library.

[image]

If you want to set this feature for all Word files on a SharePoint site, I suggest you go to site settings > [site collection features](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/enable-or-disable-site-collection-features-a2f2a5c2-093d-4897-8b7f-37f86d83df04) > active "Open Documents in Client Applications by Defualt".

[image]

Comment: Thanks Emily for response. But as I mentioned above, I am able to open the file in Desktop app only after clicking the file in SharePoint site. But my requirement is to open the word file in desktop when we click on hyperlink (https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/:w:/r/teams/TeamsSiteName/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx) to this SharePoint file from external application. This is something I was trying to achieve but couldn't do. Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by pointing to bookmarks in a Word document saved on SharePoint. I used the method described in the below link to create bookmarks in a Brochure that would open in Desktop Word Application when clicked.

https://www.success-trending.club/2020/03/linking-to-bookmark-in-word-document.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1187776)